# How to seperate regex and get every occurences?

Tags: regex

Hi I have the following string of log . I want to get every occurences with seperate comma .

```
srcnat: in:(none)(ether5) out:ether1, src-mac 11:aa:22:bb:33:cc, proto TCP (SYN), 10.5.59.207:49361->17.248.147.79:443, len 64
```

I want to get

> "srcnat: in:(none)(ether5) out:ether1"
>
> "src-mac 11:aa:22:bb:33:cc"
>
> "proto TCP (SYN)"
>
> "10.5.59.207:49361->1.2.3.44:443"

I can get "srcnat: in:(none)(ether5) out:ether1"  with regex (^[^,]*) . How can i get others separately

Comment: What language are you working with?

Comment: The new question wizard does a good job noticing: Regular expression questions get better answers if they …include a tag for **one** specific engine or language (perl, pcre, c#, etc...) …show the pattern that isn't working …Provide some examples of input text that should match, *and also* ones that shouldn't match …describe the desired results, and how the pattern isn't producing them. There are no more excuses.

Comment: I want to create Rsyslog config with this. Rsyslog running under ubuntu 16.04 server.I dont know what language . I m following documentation. Configuratin like this : $template test,"%msg:R,ERE,1,BLANK:(^[^,]*)--end%\n"

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify your language, I go with Java that I'm more comfortable with. Split with

```
myString.split(,\s+(?=(?:(?:[^']*'){2})*[^']*$), -1)
```

This allows you to split by a comma followed by a space, while ignoring the ones in a quotation.

Comment: @melpomene I assumed Java.

Answer (score 0):

What you may want is the regex `/([^,]+)(?=,)/g`.

This will match (in groups) anything that is not a comma, up until a comma is found.

This can be seen on **[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/emrxIF/1/)**, or in the following:

```js
var regex = /([^,]+)(?=,)/g;
var string = "srcnat: in:(none)(ether5) out:ether1, src-mac 11:aa:22:bb:33:cc, proto TCP (SYN), 10.5.59.207:49361->17.248.147.79:443, len 64";

console.log(string.match(regex));
```